# Rails not redirecting to object after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When saving our Video object we get a no method vide_url error when trying to redirect to the video#watch action and view the object

Admin/Video/Controller

```
def create
  @video = Video.create(user: User.first, title: params['title'], description: params['description'], file: params['video']['file'])
redirect_to @video
end
```

Video/Controller

```
def index
  @videos = Video.page(params[:page]||1)
end
def watch
  @video = Video.find_by!(id: params[:id])
end
```

Routes

```
get "video/index"
get "video/watch/:id" => 'video#watch'
namespace :admin do
  resources :video
  resources :playlist
end
```

Any idea what is going on? Is it because we are using custom routes for the videos?

Comment: Are you sure that the video is saved successfully? `create` may be returning a created but not saved video if validations are not passing.

Comment: The data get's entered into the database and shows up in the view, its just the redirect that isn't working.

Comment: It wont solve your problem, but couldn't you use "@video = Video.create params[:video]" on your admin/video/controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is your custom routes. `redirect_to @video` essentially calls `url_for @video`. From the docs for [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for):

> Relying on named routes
>
> Passing a record (like an Active Record) instead of a hash as the
>   options parameter will trigger the named route for that record. The
>   lookup will happen on the name of the class. So passing a Workshop
>   object will attempt to use the workshop_path route. If you have a
>   nested route, such as admin_workshop_path you’ll have to call that
>   explicitly (it’s impossible for url_for to guess that route).

So, because you've got a namespace around that resource you'll need to do:

```
redirect_to admin_video_path(@video)
```

or

```
redirect_to admin_video_url(@video)
```

**Update**

If you want to redirect to the watch action you'll need to either redirect to a hash of options including that action:

```
redirect_to controller: :video, action: :watch, id: @video.id
```

Or give your watch route a name in routes.rb:

```
get "video/watch/:id", to: 'video#watch', as: :watch_video
```

And redirect to that named route:

```
redirect_to watch_video_url(@video)
```

Comment: No I need it to go back to the Video controller Watch action... not to the admin.

Comment: Wow, someone's marking down aggressively! I've updated my answer to reflect the update to the question.

Comment: First one doesnt work "No route matches {:action=>"watch", :controller=>"admin/video", :id=>20}" as admin/video is namespaced to video

Answer (score 1):

Please, Try the followings.

```
def create
  @video = Video.create(user: User.first, title: params['title'], description: params['description'], file: params['video']['file'])
  redirect_to admin_video_path(@video)
end
```